# How to apply Checkstyle check IllegalType only to static fields

Tags: java, static, field, checkstyle

I'm trying to use Checkstyle ([this check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalType)) to raise a warning when a particular class is used as a type for static field. I'm doing it with this configuration and it doesn't work:

`<module name="IllegalType">
     <property name="format" value="myFullClassName"/>
     <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_STATIC"/>
</module>`

The following configuration do work, but for all fields, not only static:

`<module name="IllegalType">
    <property name="format" value="myFullClassName"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
</module>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doc](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalType), it looks like tokens have to be a `subset` of `PARAMETER_DEF`, `VARIABLE_DEF` and `METHOD_DEF`.

Comment: Thanks, Raghuram. Possibly I was seeking in the wrong direction. The following has worked for me, however I think that it is some way ugly..
    <module name="Regexp">
      <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
      <property name="format" value="static myClassName*\s[A-Za-z]*\s|static final myClassName*\s[A-Za-z\_]*\s"/>
      <property name="message" value="myClassName Objects must not be stored in static fields!"/>
    </module>